Jacoco coverage 0% after updating gradke 7.4 to 0.8.7 in Android App using EC file
We were using 7.4 gradle version with jacoco version with 0.8.5, After upgradeging from 8.7 we are getting coverage is 0% in all class file. while running JacocoReportTask then we are getting Execution on {*class.name} does  not match.
I changed version 8.8 and jacoco version 0.8.12, but still not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
